# Select maximum in array according to condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array  `[6,5,4,3,2,1,0,1]` to define a metric,
and I have selected some indices from this array according to a 
condition. The array indices are `[1,2]`. Now I want to select the element 
among the selected indices that has corresponding maximum value in metric array.

The answer for this is 1 as 1th element is maximum among indices selected.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([6,5,4,3,2,1,0,1])
idx = np.array([1,2])

y = idx[ np.argmax(x[idx]) ]
```